# Multiple PDFs in different tabs

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, viewcontroller, tabbar

I have a Tabbar iOS application with three tabs. I have each tab set up to be a UIWebView. I want each web view to display a different PDF. How do I assign, through code, each webview to its corresponding pdf?

Answer (score 0):

It will look something like this in your `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    WebViewController *webViewController1 = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtURL:@"urlToPDF1"];
    WebViewController *webViewController2 = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtURL:@"urlToPDF2"];
    WebViewController *webViewController3 = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithPDFAtURL:@"urlToPDF3"];

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:webViewController1, webViewController2, webViewController3, nil]];
    self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

You will need to have a view controller that holds the `UIWebView`, and could look something like:

```
// WebViewController.h
@interface WebViewController : UIViewController

@end

// WebViewController.m
@interface WebViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *_pdfURL;

@end

@implementation WebViewController
@synthesize _pdfURL;

- (id)initWithPDFAtURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _pdfURL = url;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Load the PDF into a UIWebView
}
```